# How to setup api endpoint in Node tu run cli scripts on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, command-line-interface

I have found an interesting node cli script on github. I want to use it on heroku to setup an automated service that I will query to obtain some updated info that are created when the script run. How I can setup an api endpoint in nodejs and is it possible to run cli node scripts in heroku apps? I'm a new to node programming and some help will be appreciated.

Comment: if it is a node cli, you may to `require` it and call it passing the `args`

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon thanks for the qucik reply. It's a node cli script and it need to take a `.txt` file as input. This file is hosted on github and I want to fetch it using axios and then process it. The flow is a bit complex, I need to create an api endpoint that will be called once a day from a chrome extension to check for updates.

Comment: After the api call and when the file is ready after that is processed from the cli script, I want to send it back to the chrome extension to replace an existing json file content, but for this part I'm not sure if it's possible